# Why does POSIX specify wctomb as non-thread-safe, but not mbtowc?

Tags: c, thread-safety, posix, multibyte

In XSH [2.9.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_01), `wctomb` is listed as one of the functions which is not required to be thread-safe. However, the opposite conversion function, `mbtowc`, does not appear in the list. On an implementation with encodings that use shift states, neither has a thread-safe API, and it makes no sense that one is required to be thread-safe and the other is not, while neither can be thread-safe without forbidding stateful encodings.

Likewise for `wcstombs` (which is in the list) and `mbstowcs` (which is not). Since both of these functions operate on entire strings which begin and end in the initial shift state, they are not stateful, their APIs are thread-safe, and again it makes no sense that one direction is specified to be thread-safe but not the other.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: In the link to which you refer there is a comment which may shed some light.

"The wcrtomb() and wcsrtombs() functions need not be thread-safe if passed a NULL ps argument."

I suspect this may lead you to some further understanding.

Comment: @David: You're looking at the functions with `r` in their names, which are different from the ones in the question.

Comment: @R.. I know that. My point is that `wcrtomb` is thread-safe when a non-NULL ps is passed to it. Presumably when ps == NULL then wcrtomb is equivalent to wctomb.

Comment: @R.. Further speculation. `wctomb` doesn't need to be thread-safe because you can call `wcrtomb` if you want thread-safety. For `mbtowc` there is no `r` version so it has to be thread-safe. All pure guess work mind you!!

Comment: @David, I was thinking along the same lines (and deleted my answer suggesting the same), but @R.. is correct. The re-entrant version of non thread safe functions _don't_ have to synchronize internally if the pointer to PS is NULL. POSIX is saying (specifically) `mbtowc` need not be thread safe, which I also find questionable.

Comment: @Tim Is that what you meant? POSIX states that `mbtowc` **is** thread-safe.

Comment: @David - I meant `wctomb`, I'm a little tired and brain dead tonight, sorry :) I better go to bed before I start getting my 'mords wixed'.

Comment: Yes, my question is about the asymmetry between the mb->wc and wc->mb directions with regard to thread-safety, and why a function which presumably cannot be thread-safe is required to be. (I suppose a strict reading of the standard implies that a conformant implementation cannot support encodings with shift states, which would be a very *positive* requirement in my mind...)

Comment: @R.. functions can often be thread-safe simply by means of using internal locks

Comment: Is it possible that `mbtowc` and `mbstowcs` were inadvertently left off the list of functions that don't need to be thread safe?  Have you looked at the source to any open source implementations to see if they found some magic way to be thread safe?  It wouldn't be the first time a standard had errors or omissions in it.

Comment: `mbtowc` (and `wctomb`) are naturally thread-safe except on implementations which support encodings with shift states (which are so pathological and full of security issues that they should never be supported). `mbstowcs` and `wcstombs` are also naturally thread-safe even with shift states unless you intentionally break them.

Comment: Can't look up POSIX drafts/related discussions for this :^( They are not freely available as per IEEE policy. So far, speculations is the best you get.

Answer (score 3):

As you noted in the question, `wctomb` has, or at least is allowed to have, a (hidden) "shift state": see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wctomb.html and compare this to `wcrtomb`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wcrtomb.html which has an explicit "state" pointer.

POSIX basically allows the programmer to implement `wctomb` as a call to `wcrtomb` using a `static` variable to hold the shift state.  If that variable is not a per-thread item, it won't be thread-safe.

(all of this is pretty obvious and is contained in your question, I'm just repeating it for clarity here)

Note that no argument to `wctomb` gives you any sort of explicit control of the hidden shift state (if there is one).  Specifically, you *can't* reset it to the start state.

But now look at `mbtowc`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mbtowc.html where the text says:

> For a state-dependent encoding, this function is placed into its initial state by a call for which its character pointer argument, s, is a null pointer. Subsequent calls with s as other than a null pointer shall cause the internal state of the function to be altered as necessary. A call with s as a null pointer shall cause this function to return a non-zero value if encodings have state dependency, and 0 otherwise. If the implementation employs special bytes to change the shift state, these bytes shall not produce separate wide-character codes, but shall be grouped with an adjacent character.

That is, they give you an explicit way to detect and control the hidden state (if it exists).  So even if it exists and is not thread-specific, you can "do your own control" as it were.

While I can't swear to it, I think this is why `mbtowc` is not listed as being non-thread-safe.

(This is not the way I would have written the text in the standard, though!  Then again, if I had my way, a lot of these functions would not even exist. :-) )

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental asymmetry is that ISO C requires that wide characters have fixed width (same for all characters), and that the encoding does not have shift states.  In contrast, multibyte encoding is dependent on the locale and may have varying character width and also shift states.

All the four functions have internal state kept between calls (`mbstowcs` and `wcstombs` also have to because they convert only a specified number of bytes as opposed to full strings that would otherwise finish in the initial shift state).

There is a subtle difference of what the internal state consists of in case of the string conversions.  For `mbstowcs`, a whole number of wide characters is converted in a single call.  This is because wide characters have a fixed width, and also because the `n` parameter of the call is specified in characters, not bytes.  In contrast, for `wcstombs` the `n` parameter is specified in bytes, not in multi-byte characters.  Consequently, the state kept for `wcstombs` has to include not only the shift state, but also the remainder of a partially output multibyte character.  Because the state is thus multi-part, operations (load and store) on it are not going to be atomic on a typical architecture without additional locking.

At this point it is important to remind ourselves that "thread safety" has a pretty technical meaning in POSIX, namely that parallel invocations are logically serializable.  It does not mean that parallel usage is necessarily very useful.  As all the four functions keep internal state, it is hard to imagine a caller who processes a single linear string (at a time) left to right, but spreading the calls across multiple threads.  This is witnessed by the introduction of `mbrtowc`, `wcrtomb`, `mbsrtowcs` and `wcstombs` in Amendment 1 to the ISO C 89/90, with the `r` flag standing specifically for "reentrant".

I cannot exactly explain why having an "atomically accessible" internal state should make it easier to make the respective call easier to implement in a thread safe way (because there sometimes have to be multiple accesses, load and store, during a single call), but maybe it is because the burden of additional locking (and reloading) is only imposed in the rarely visited code branch where an actual shift state is taking place.

There is also another catch to explain.  A concurrent thread may call `setlocale` changing the character encoding (`LC_CTYPE`) category of the locale.  ISO C standard specifies that such an action causes the current state (and, by the way, even a state well captured using `wcrtomb`) to become undefined.  This is because the shift states of different locales may not map to each other in useful or specified ways. Although this is a threaded scenario that has the potential of breaking even the "reentrant" family of functions, it does not necessarily pose an obstacle to a formally thread safe implementation because the locale setting can be cached throughout each call.

Comment: I see how `wctomb` could have an internal state in a stateful encoding when avoiding redundant shift sequences, but `mbtowc` would then be equally stateful...

Comment: @R..: You are right.  `mbtowc` actually is stateful as well.  And worse, `mbstowcs` and `wcstombs` are no better (they are `n` character equivalents of their `1` character equivalents and so they do not start  in the initial state either).  I will do more research and fix the first half of my answer tonight, if I can make it out.  This is a really intriguing question!

Comment: My bounty expired, but if you do manage to find any good reason for this, I'll see if I can open another one to assign it.

Comment: @R..: I switched the focus of the answer from "shift states" to "partial characters".  I don't think it merits the bounty (you can still award it in the next 7 hours) but I hope that you will find it to be a somewhat logical explanation of the assymmetry in POSIX.

Comment: +1 This is a fantastically insightful answer, thank you. I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The common way to "Unicode-enable" a C program is to use `wchar_t` in place of `char` everywhere and call the wide character versions of narrow character standard library functions. I like this approach because it's immediately clear that a variable of type `wchar_t*` either points to a `wchar_t` object or a wide string, but a variable of type `char*` can point to a `char` object, a narrow string in the native char encoding, or a multibyte string in any of the dozens of supported character encodings. With so many fundamentally different meanings of `char*`, the programmer must be extremely careful to not, for example, pass a UTF-8-encoded multibyte string to a function that expects a narrow string, or pass a multibyte string in the current encoding to a function that expects a UTF-8-encoded string. Perhaps the idea of ensuring that `mbtowc` and `mbstowcs` (functions that convert multibyte strings to wide strings) are thread safe, but not the functions that convert from wide strings to multibyte strings, is to persuade the programmer to always keep string data in program memory in wide character format, where each character represents exactly one member of the execution character set, rather than a mix of narrow strings and multibyte strings utilizing possibly different character encodings. Perhaps the standard writers were thinking that that is the more useful approach, or would be the more common.

If you consider writing multithreaded Unicode-enabled server software in C, then following the pattern of keeping string data in wide string format helps to enforce a separation between string data read "from the wire" and string data in program memory. Whenever a new message comes in containing a payload of string data, the C routine that parses the message and its string payload can use narrow-char I/O functions with multibyte-to-wide character converting functions to read the string into program memory. If multiple threads parse incoming messages—as is typical—then it is highly desirable for `mbstowcs` to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is simply based on the assumption that with a set of wide character encoded data, the programmer can predict how much memory needs to be allocated/freed per thread because of the fixed width of the code point. But when going in the other direction, depending on the encoding, it might not be "predictable" how much memory will need to be allocated in advance, thus creating greater room for error.

Update: after having found an older version of the standard, I noticed that there is a difference in the wording in the [man page for the wctomb() function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wctomb.html): "The wctomb() function need not be reentrant. A function that is not required to be reentrant is not required to be thread-safe." I think this suggests another implicit assumption made in the standard: mbtowc() is or should be reentrant...

Comment: `MB_CUR_MAX` and `MB_LEN_MAX` exist for this purpose, but this has nothing to do with thread-safety...